# Why is it `있잖아요` not `이잖아요`?

Tags: grammar, meaning

This is a sentence from a video on VLIVE with the English translation.
Why is it `있잖아요` not `이잖아요`?
The translation "that IS" so it makes more sense to me to use `이다` there instead.

> VLIVE 하면 하는 거 있잖아요.  댓글 읽기 
>   --> That's what we do (reading comment) on VLIVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'이다', verbs, adjectives or ‘-으시-’, ‘-었-’, ‘-겠-’ **+ -잖아요**

- 있잖아요 = 있(다) + 잖아요
- 이잖아요 = 이(다) + 잖아요

=>

- VLIVE 하면 하는 거(것이) + 있다(there is) + 잖아요 (o)
- VLIVE 하면 하는 거(것이) + 이다(is) + 잖아요 (x)

"That's what we do (reading comment) on VLIVE." is not word-to-word translation, so you may feel confused. 
Literally it means, "If we do VLIVE, **there is** what we normally do. That is reading comments." Here, 있다('there is') is more natural than 이다(just 'is') in the context. So you need to use -하는 거 있잖아요.

Answer (score 2):

"X 있잖아요" is an idiomatic expression, similar to, "Why, you know, X."  (Literally, it means "isn't there X?" - from which it's easy to understand how this means "you know".)  For example,

> A: 찬장에서 밀가루 좀 꺼내 줄래? = Can you pass me the flour from the cupboard?
>
> B: 어느 게 밀가루야? = Which one is flour?
>
> A: 파란 종이 봉지에 들어있는 거 **있잖아.** = **You see,** the one in the blue paper bag.

On the other hand, "X(이)잖아요" literally means "isn't it X?", so you could use it in a different situation.  For example:

> B: 부침개에 밀가루를 그렇게 많이 넣으려고? = You are pouring so much flour on the pancake (mix)?
>
> A: 왜? 부침개가 원래 밀가루 맛으로 먹는 **거잖아?** = Why (not)? Pancakes are supposed to have floury taste, **isn't it?**

A note of caution: when you connect 거 with -이잖아 (or any other form of the copula -이다), the 이 disappears, so it must be 거다/거냐/거잖아, not 거이다/거이냐/거이잖아.  (거 is already an informal form of 것, so adding the full -이다 after that is impossible, as far as I know.)